# MiKTeX Package Manager Crashes

Tags: errors

Whenever I try to install some package from MiKTeX Package Manager, the packet manager crashes. Why would this be happening?

Problem signature:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   mpm_mfc.exe
Application Version:    2.9.4196.0
Application Timestamp:  4e3327b8
Fault Module Name:  MiKTeX209-core.dll
Fault Module Version:   2.9.4792.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 511beb86
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   0008b354
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: A program crash is likely to be 'off topic', I think, as it's likely only the developer can give a useful answer. Have you reported this to Christian Schenk?

Comment: I use LaTeX mainly in linux, but yesterday I needed miktex on my windows 7 box. So I installed the latest 64 bits version of miktex. To my surprise I am getting this same crash.

Comment: Some mirrors are down. I think I've been using the Polish one and switched to the Austrian one and that worked.

Comment: There seems to be a problem when you use the "use nearest repository" option. Try if it works if you select a specific repository.

Comment: Maybe it's the global repository index that's down, see http://miktex.org/pkg/repositories

Comment: I think there was some temporary issue with downloading the packages from the repository which I believe is working fine now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about a temporary problem with MikTeX repositories.