# Package Manager MikTex 2.9 crashes if you install any script

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

I tried installing any script from the Package Manager of latest version of MikTeX but when you try any script, the package manager crashes. I have tried it with and without the admin mode. Moreover, I tried it on different Windows 7 systems, but didn't work on any.

Do you guys also currently experiencing it with MikTeX 2.9?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any error codes? Anything that could potentially ID the problem?  (This isn't the same issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137589, is it?)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Yes it's the same issue.

Comment: Please don't duplicate posts.  The other question is at least decently active; please focus effort on that question.